# JavaFX sample code does not play video it just shows media player

Tags: java, javafx, media-player, media, ubuntu-14.04

I have created a sample code on Netbeans - Ubuntu 14.04 -the video plays normally outside this      ..example from the same path.The path is on my machine only.

```
package javafxapplication1;

import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println("workingDir"+workingDir);
        File f = new File(workingDir, "the_appartition.flv");


        //try{

        //Media m = new Media(f.toURI().toString());

        Media m = new Media("http://192.168.1.251/test/videos/the_appartition.flv");
        System.out.println("media "+m.getSource());
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
        MediaView mv = new MediaView(mp);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(mv);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 960, 540));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Video Player 1");
        primaryStage.show();

        mp.play();
        /*}
        catch(Throwable t)
        {
              t.printStackTrace();

        }*/
    }
}
```

What can be the reason that it shows blank media player without any error/exception.

Comment: You should add error handling to your code as documented in the [JavaFX media package javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html).

Comment: I have added error block as well to catch MediaException however no exception is being thrown

Comment: When you say "the video plays normally outside this", what does that mean?  How do you play the video and get it to work?  If it plays normally, why the question?  Is the video encoded to a format as specified in the [JavaFX media documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html)?  e.g. is a VP6 encoded FLV? (such files are extremely rare).

Comment: Does your system meet minimum requirements for [JavaFX Playback](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html)?  e.g. update your question to include info on the GLIB version you are running as well as the versions of libavcodec and libavformat installed.  Also include the code version with error handling in your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fixed JIRA for this issue

[[Linux] JavaFX Media does not run on Ubuntu 14.04](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37914)

It is fixed in Java 8u40 version. If you really want to run this, you might want to download and install the early available version of the JDK from [JDK™ 8u40 Early Access Releases](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html)

Comment: I installed this JDK early access release still it shows white blank area